# Listview is not showing first entry

Tags: android-listview

I am showing all files from server in listview.

Files on server are as follows:
binary.txt/erpTestBench/muneem.php/oglPrahova/permitCore/workOrderTestBench/

Listview is showing all files except binary.txt file.

My listview xml file is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
        >


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/path"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#2377ff"/>
    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" android:background="#2f3fc8" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:dividerHeight="15dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:text="No Data"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:background="#2f3fc8"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingTop="6dp" android:paddingBottom="6dp" android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout" android:background="#346684">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:src="@drawable/power"
                android:onClick="bt_Quit" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/back"
                android:onClick="back"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="71dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/home"

                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:onClick="home"/>
    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

my java file is as follows:

```
public class serv extends ListActivity {
    private String m_urlString="XXXXX";
//    private String result;

    private List<String> m_item = null;
    private List<String> m_path = null;
    private String m_root="XXXX";
    private String m_result;
    private TextView m_myPath;
    static private String m_pos;
    private String m_backposition;
    private String m_fileURL;


    int m_downloadedSize = 0;
    int m_totalSize = 0;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.file_chooser);

        View v= findViewById(R.id.rowtext);


        m_myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);
        m_fileURL="http://192.168.1.30/muneem/";
        Http_connection f=new Http_connection();
        f.execute("");


    }

    class Http_connection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected Void  doInBackground(String... urls)
        {

            try
            {
                URL url= new URL(m_urlString);
                HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                con.connect();
                int statusCode=con.getResponseCode();
                if (statusCode==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    m_result="";
                    while ((line=in.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        m_result=m_result+"\n"+line;
                    }
                    in.close();
                    con.disconnect();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            getDir(m_urlString);


                        }
                    });

                }
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                //            bundle.putString("Error","Problem with URL");

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                //              bundle.putString("Error","Problem with connection");

            }


            return null;
        }
    }
    private void getDir(String dirPath)
    {


        String[] r=m_result.split("/");
        m_myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
        m_item = new ArrayList<String>();
        m_path = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int k=0;k<r.length;k++)
        {
            if (r[k].contains("."))
            {
                m_item.add(r[k]);

            }
            else
            {
                m_item.add(r[k]+"/");
            }
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(serv.this, R.layout.row, m_item);
        setListAdapter(fileList);

    }
```

Comment: What's the value of `m_result` at the start of `getDir()`? Can you narrow the problem down to `getDir()` or `doInBackground()`, please?

Comment: its showing all files sir list view is not showing first record in cell but when i click on first cell i get the required result

Comment: the issue i am facing is that List view is not showing first entry in first cell its showing some 3-4 dots overthere

Comment: But if you put a breakpoint at the start of `getDir()`, debug, and inspect the value of `m_result` at that point, what is it? Is it the value you'd expect? If so, the problem is probably later. If it already looks wrong, the problem is probably earlier.

Comment: Hey that works.I was getting "\n" at start of m_result thats why it was not showing first entry. answer my post i will accept it. thanks again for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data goes through a few steps before making it to the ListView, so the source of the problem could be in one of a few different steps. If you debug your code and check the value of `m_result` at the beginning of `getDir()`, you can determine where the problem is coming from. If the value is as expected, there's probably an issue in `getDir()`, whereas if there's a problem with the string, the issue is probably in `doInBackground()` (and easy to spot if you know what's wrong with the result, as it turned out).